# Добавление полей в форму с помощью JS

Tags: html, javascript

Здравствуйте.
Есть код, который добавляет в форму сразу 2 поля. Хочу его немного изменить, чтобы добавлял по одному полю при каждом нажатии кнопки "Добавить". Кроме того, нужно, чтобы параметр name у input увеличивался на единицу у каждого добавленного поля.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Добавление полей в форму</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
function addfields() {
document.getElementById('twofields').style.display="block";
}
</script>

  </head>
  <body style="margin-top:140px;">
 <form id="myform">
Имя: <input type="text" />  <br/>
Дата рождения:  <input type="text" /><br/>
Пароль:<input type="password" /><br/>
<input type="button" onclick="addfields()" value="Добавить два поля"/><br/>
<span id="twofields" style="display:none">
Отчество: <input type="text" /> <br/>
Ещё поле:<input type="text" />  <br/>
</span>
<input type="submit" />
 </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Batyabest, во-первых, я вас огорчу, т.к. тут нет кода, который именно добавляет новые поля формы, а есть только код, который показывает изначально скрытые поля. Поэтому не плохо бы уточнить задачу: какие поля вы хотите добавлять и какие значения атрибутов name у них должны быть. Во-вторых, имеет ли смысл новым полям инкрементировать значение этим полям? Может просто передавать массивом?

    <input type="text" name="some_name[]" value="1">
    <input type="text" name="some_name[]" value="2">
    <input type="text" name="some_name[]" value="N">

Comment: Мне нужно реализовать добавление фото в профиль. В базу будет заносится путь, в дополнительные поля. Называть их я хочу photo, photo1 и т.д., но делать сразу много полей нет желания, поэтому хочу сделать одно поле для загрузки, а кому надо, тот добавит больше полей.
_____

У меня пути к файлам будут прописываться в виде JSON строки, не возникнет ли с этим трудностей?

Comment: @Batyabest, какая разница, в каком виде вы будете записывать? На сервере вы получаете массив изображений, в цикле сохраняете их в нужную папку, формируя пути к ним. Все эти пути записываете в массив и преобразуете в JSON-строку.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. Я сейчас пробую, у меня пишет Cannot call method 'querySelector' of null. В чем беда?
____

Разобрался, перенес скрипт после формы. А как мне отметить твой ответ верным?

Comment: @Batyabest, если всё устраивает, то отмечайте. Перевел комментарий в ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@Batyabest](/users/22866/batyabest)](/users/22866/batyabest), теперь более понятно. Смотрите [такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/xd52qfuy/3/). Как я и говорил, вам достаточно будет отправлять все фото массивом.

Comment: Дружище, у меня все это дело на ModX, не прокатило массивом сохранять, пустое поле сохранилось, можешь переписать код, чтобы name увеличивался на единицу?

Comment: @Batyabest, я, конечно, не знаком с ModX, но что-то грызут меня сомнения, что он не умеет работать с массивами изображений. Как бы ни было, вот [как вы просили][1]. У полей имена "user_photo_1", "user_photo_2" и т.д.

   [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/xd52qfuy/11/

Comment: Да я тоже думал, все ок будет, но почему-то пустое значение записалось вместо массива. Он при сохранении в БД кодирует все в JSON, может, в этом дело. Каждому полю присваивается поле и значение {photo:...} и т.д. Завтра еще спрошу у спецов по ModX, в чем дело, если интересно, могу здесь отписать, что мне ответят.
За код большое спасибо, выручили сильно.

Comment: > спрошу у спецов по ModX в чем дело, если интересно, могу здесь отписать

@Batyabest, напишите. Кому-то точно пригодится.